# can't use a global javascript variable outside function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I'm using this function with google maps

```
var currgeocoder;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position, html5Error) {
    geo_loc = processGeolocationResult(position);
    currLatLong = geo_loc.split(",");
    initializeCurrent(currLatLong[0], currLatLong[1]);
});

function processGeolocationResult(position) {
    html5Lat = position.coords.latitude; //Get latitude
    html5Lon = position.coords.longitude; //Get longitude
    html5TimeStamp = position.timestamp; //Get timestamp
    html5Accuracy = position.coords.accuracy; //Get accuracy in meters
    return html5Lat + ", " + html5Lon;
}
alert(html5Lat);
```

As you see I didn't use `var` to make the variable global, but the `alert()` doesn't work and if I place the `alert()` inside the function it works well. So how to make the `html5lat` and `html5lon` global to be accessed from another function?

Comment: The issue is you're alerting it before `processGeolocationResult` has run - `getCurrentPosition` results in an asychronous call.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with scope, but with timing.